# Parametricity in OCaml

Tags: generics, ocaml, containers

I am a complete beginner in OCaml, but I keep seeing code similar to the following in introductory examples

```
let sum = List.fold ~f:(+.) ~init:0.0
```

What bothers me in this snippet is the explicit use of `List.fold`. In most languages I know, the explicit type of the container would be abstracted by the use of an interface, a trait or a typeclass, so that one could reuse this code to sum an array or any other sequential container.

What is the OCaml way to make this more generic?

Comment: You are using `List` so your function can only take lists. There is no easy way to make it accept any "sequence" like type (it won't typecheck, there is no "any" type in Ocaml). You might consider functors.

Comment: If http://www.lpw25.net/ml2014.pdf happens, in future OCaml's it may become possible to do away with the `List.` part in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more generic solution is to use functors:

```
module type Foldable = sig 
  type 'a t
  val fold : 'a t -> init:'b -> f:('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b
end

module MakeSum(Container : Foldable) = struct
  let sum xs = Container.fold ~f:(+.) ~init:0.0
end
```

As you may noticed this extra parametricity comes with significant syntactic overhead. Indeed, we can reuse interfaces from `Core` to reduce it:

```
module MakeSum(Container : Container.T) = struct
  let sum xs = Container.fold ~f:(+.) ~init:0.0
end
```

or

```
module MakeSum(Container : Container.S1) = struct
  let sum xs = Container.fold ~f:(+.) ~init:0.0
end
```

Also, as an example, you maybe mostly interested not in parametrizing over container types, but over the summation operation and zero value. This particular example is implemented using first class functors (another option) in OCaml Core library, and every container implements this function:

```
  (** Returns the sum of [f i] for i in the container *)
  val sum
    : (module Commutative_group.S with type t = 'sum)
    -> t -> f:(elt -> 'sum) -> 'sum
```

### Update

Indeed, at your particular case we can generalize even without functors, since you do not need to know type in order to implement your code. So we can just define generic `sum` as:

```
let sum fold xs = fold ~f:(+.) ~init:0.0
```

Comment: It should be `val fold : 'a t -> init:'b -> f:('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b` in your `Foldable` sig? It seems that you miss a ` -> 'b`